# Pointers with 2D arrays in c++

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, multidimensional-array, reference

I'm working on a simple program which uses a 2D array of characters but I think my understanding is off because I'm getting some odd results. I made a class which handles all the text. My constructor looks something like this:

```
// I use char * <var_name> here, because it's what I've found while searching online,
// but I'm honestly not sure what it *actually* results in in the context of a 2D array
char *options[3][20] = {"text1", "text2", "text3"};
cout << x;
// this displays the same hex address (0x61fd20),
// whether x is options, options[0], *options, *options[0], &options or &options[0] - I have no idea why
```

Then, later in the same class:

```
displayOptions () {
    cout << &options; // outputs 0x61ff28 (slightly different address)
                     // any other modifier to options (as shown above) outputs nothing
```

I know I'm supposed to ask only one thing at a time, so my ultimate question is this: **how exactly do I initialise and display the contents of a 2D array?**

If related to why I'm getting this wrong, why do all those different variations on "options" print the same thing, and why does it change when the same variable is used in a different method in the same class?

Comment: Why not just use `std::string` and some standard c++ containers? Or possibly the multidimensional arrays from boost?

Comment: You have a 2D array of pointers on the LHS and an initializer that is compatible with a 1D array of `const char*` on the LHS. It isn't clear why you think you need 2D, and what the size 3 of the 1st dimension represents.

Comment: Could you clarify what you are trying to do?  You are saying you want a 2D array, but as was mentioned above, you are initializing a 1D array.  Do you actually need an array of arrays of char pointers or do you just need an array of char pointers?

Comment: @DanMašek I was more hoping to get some understanding on how to handle multidimensional arrays in C++, but I'll stick with the std::string route if what I was doing is a silly way to go about things

Comment: @bradimus I have a couple sentences which I need to reuse a couple times in the code. My understanding is that a sentence is like a 1D array of characters, so a grouping of sentences would be a 2D array

Comment: @AlKnemeyer Fair enough, for learning purposes. However from practical point of view, it's always better to reuse existing (and well tested) code, if it satisfies your requirements.

Comment: A quick note on pointers. `*pointer` and `pointer[0]` refer to the same place in memory: The start of a block of memory. In the `char *options[3][20]` case, `options` is one contiguous block of memory, so `options`, `*options`, and `**options` all reference the beginning of the memory block as do `options[0]`, and `options[0][0]`. This only applies to a contiguous block. If you have stitched together pointers to different blocks of memory you will get different results.

Comment: Just in case anyone runs into the same issue with variables behaving well in the constructor and badly in other member functions, the reason my "options" variable was misbehaving in other parts of the class is because I declared it at the start of my constructor (as well as a private variable in the class), limiting it's scope to the constructor (local variable style)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An array of arrays is different than an array of pointers. In your code, your `options` array is actually *both* (an array of arrays of pointers; no joke), and probably unintentionally so.

To have a clearer understanding of your declaration, taking `char *options[3][20]` to [cdecl.org](http://cdecl.ridiculousfish.com/?q=char+*options%5B3%5D%5B20%5D) (a most awesome website for learning declaration syntax and worthy of bookmarking) gives us:

> declare options as array 3 of array 20 of pointer to char

Given that, what it *appears* you're trying to do is one of the following:

- Declare an array of three pointers to constant strings.
- Declare an array of three `char[20]` with initial values provided.

Only one of these, the latter, is an array of arrays. The former is an array of pointers to const `char` data.

**Array of three pointers to `const` strings**

The string literals are `const`, and such should be treated as such. Also note the `3` is optional, as it can be deduced from the initialization:

```
char const *options[3] = {"text1", "text2", "text3"};
```

or

```
char const *options[] = {"text1", "text2", "text3"};
```

**Array of `char` arrays**

No pointers are required. You simply do this (and note again, the `3` is optional, as it is again deducible from the initializer):

```
char options[3][20] = {"text1", "text2", "text3"};
```

or

```
char options[][20] = {"text1", "text2", "text3"};
```

The two biggest differences between these two approaches

- One is an array of pointers, the other an array of `char` arrays
- For the former, the array (of pointers) is mutable, but the strings are *not*. For the latter, both the array and the strings (the arrays of `char`) are mutable.

Answer (score 0):

You have to add a second index.

so to get "Text1" you use `options[0][0]`. (you made a 3x20 array and have only initialized the first row)

To initialize a 2D array, you format it this way. (Should be looking this up btw. Fundamental stuff)

```
char *TwoD_example[x][y] = {a1,a2,a3, ...}, {b1, b2, b3, ...}, .....
```

Edit: Forgot to add curly braces...

```
char *TwoD_example[x][y] = {{a1,a2,a3, ...}, {b1, b2, b3, ...}, .....}
```

Comment: Ahhh, I see, I thought char *options[3][20] = {"text1", "text2", "text3"}; treats "text1" as the first array of chars, "text2" as the second etc. I did look things up but didn't really understand - thanks though, I think I get it now. Sorry, I've been finding this really tricky

Comment: @AlKnemeyer: You don't have arrays of chars, you have arrays of pointers to chars.

Comment: @AlKnemeyer No worries, pointers get confusing....But as Ben Voigt mentioned its not a 2D array of chars, it is a 2D array of pointers to chars. Pointers point to addresses. In this case an address to a char. If you just want a 2D array of chars and have no reason to use pointers, then take the * off. But if you take the * off, then you can't use initialize it that way because you're putting strings in there. You'll have to use std:string instead of char as others have mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to create a class to initialize and display the contents of a 2D array.

You could initialize the array using a loop:

```
int **options = new int*[row_number];

for(int i=0;i<row_number;i++){
    options[i] = new int[col_number];
}
```

You create an array of pointers. Also keep in mind that you should use `delete` to de-allocate from the heap.

You can access the 2D array to display the contents like this:

```
options[3][20]
```